# Why is my RegEx pattern working for one string, but not the others?

Tags: c#, regex

This feels like such a simple request, but I cannot figure out what is going on here, and have been messing with different RegEx testers for a while now.

My RegEx pattern: `\b(?=<GTOL-[A-Z]*>)`

If it matters, the command I am calling in my code (C#): `Regex.Split(Text, @"\b(?=<GTOL-[A-Z]*>)").ToList();`

[The string that will successfully be split:](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3d%3cGTOL-%5bA-Z%5d*%3e%29&i=%3cGTOL-POSI%3e.010%3cMOD-MMC%3eB-C%3cGTOL-POSI%3e.002%3cMOD-FMC%3e) `<GTOL-POSI>.010<MOD-MMC>B-C<GTOL-POSI>.002<MOD-FMC>`; Returns: `<GTOL-POSI>.010<MOD-MMC>B-C` ; `<GTOL-POSI>.002<MOD-FMC>`

[The string that will not split as expected:](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3d%3cGTOL-%5bA-Z%5d*%3e%29&i=%3cGTOL-POSI%3e%3cMOD-DIAM%3e.004%3cMOD-MMC%3eHC%3cMOD-MMC%3e%3cGTOL-POSI%3e.030%3cMOD-MMC%3eD-E%3cMOD-FMC%3e+) `<GTOL-POSI><MOD-DIAM>.004<MOD-MMC>HC<MOD-MMC><GTOL-POSI>.030<MOD-MMC>D-E<MOD-FMC>`; Should return (but doesn't): `<GTOL-POSI><MOD-DIAM>.004<MOD-MMC>HC<MOD-MMC>` ; `<GTOL-POSI>.030<MOD-MMC>D-E<MOD-FMC>`

[Another string that will not split as expected:](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3d%3cGTOL-%5bA-Z%5d*%3e%29&i=%3cGTOL-POSI%3e%3cMOD-DIAM%3e.005%3cMOD-MMC%3eAD-E%3cMOD-MMC%3e%3cGTOL-PERP%3e.001A) `<GTOL-POSI><MOD-DIAM>.005<MOD-MMC>AD-E<MOD-MMC><GTOL-PERP>.001A`; Should return (but doesn't): `<GTOL-POSI><MOD-DIAM>.005<MOD-MMC>AD-E<MOD-MMC>` ; `<GTOL-PERP>.001A`

Comment: There is not word boundary `\b` between `><` You can write the pattern as `(?<!^\s*)(?=<GTOL-[A-Z]*>)` https://regex101.com/r/mVix6w/1

Comment: This works, if you make it as answer I will mark as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not word boundary between the `><` and as there seem to be at least 1 or more uppercase characters, then quantifier can be `+` to match 1 or more times.

If you don't want to split at the start of the string, creating an empty entry in the result list, you can assert using a negative lookbehind `(?<!^\s*)`  that there are not optional whitespace chars to the left after the start of the string.

```
(?<!^\s*)(?=<GTOL-[A-Z]*>)
```

See a [regex .NET demo](https://regex101.com/r/bMKAI6/1).